# How to get the text before $el with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
<cite>
    text here...
    <a id="target_element"></a>
</cite>
```

How to get the text before `#target_element`?

Comment: Can you tell us about #target_element parent node ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#target_element").parent().contents().filter(function(){ 
       return this.nodeType == 3; 
}).text();
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/byfSJ/)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the prettiest solution but it will work in that specific case:

```
$('#target_element').parent().text();
```

It is best to put that text in another element, like a span. Otherwise, that text can get messed up really easily. If it was in a span, you could do something like:

```
$('#target_element').prev().text();
```

That way you will run into less errors.

---

EDIT

I found [another way](http://old.nabble.com/getting-text-in-between-text-nodes-td18721532s27240.html):

```
var elementClone = $('#target_element').clone();
elementClone.children().remove();
elementClone.text();
```

Comment: Is there a general solution for this?

Comment: oh no,I don't want the text of `<a>`, sorry @Kerry, I can't change the html structure.

Comment: See my updated answer -- I know of no way to get text without the other elements

Answer (score 0):

at first time make a place for replacement:

```
<div id="target"></div>
<a id="target_element"></a>
```